# Ignore missing imports in webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

is it possible in webpack to ignore imports that cannot be resolved? To change imports to for example `undefined`. I would need to control this behavior by regex or function. So if the missing import conforms to some rules, then it would be replaced `undefined` otherwise it would throw an error as normal.

So i would like to achieve this logic:

```
if module is resolved then
    import it normally
else
    if module import matching regex then
        replace it with undefined
    else 
        throw error
```

I tried IgnorePlugin, but it ignores import always, even if it exists. I tried searching for a viable way in documentation, e.g. in `resolve` options, but there is nothing that could help.
Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You could also try something like this

```javascript
let m = undefined;
try {
    m = require('somemodule');
} catch (ex) {
    console.warn('somemodule not found')
}
if (m) {
    m.doStuff();
}
```

Comment: How can i check the filename? I need to check it in a function, not write down each module name.

Comment: This would go to the webpack configuration. The source code would just import the module (and have precations for "undefined"), but as I said, I am not shure if that works.

Comment: No, really, this doesn't solve my problem at all.

Comment: Removed the config. Did you try the other idea?

Comment: I need it to be more intelligent and dynamic. I want just import the module and let webpack resolve. Not check each module whether it is there. Besides, I use `import`.

Comment: Then make it that way. Make a function out of it. But you cant overwrite the import keyword. I didn't use import because You need newer versions of ECMA Script to do conditional imports. You can even await imports now. Bit i don't know if WebPack supports that.